# How to get rows with only unique names extracted

Tags: r, perl, awk

I have a set of data that looks like this

```
Gene    U2803   U2823   U2840   U2841   U2862   U2872   U2897   U2982   U2991   U2994   U2998   U2999   U3001   U3007   U3012   U2980
A1BG-AS 7.3159  9.3802  10.77   8.701   13.6066 8.3253  9.0556  9.8801  9.0776  11.2029 7.61    10.8403 9.2378  12.1697 9.7482  5.5327
A1BG    7.4715  5.2955  10.2275 6.3606  10.1463 5.9968  6.2673  8.6119  6.153   6.7903  4.0843  13.0875 6.8167  8.3186  6.7643  5.14
A1CF    0   0   0   0   0.0026  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0037  0
A2LD1   1.776   1.125   1.3508  1.2489  2.1252  2.1057  1.0177  1.6063  1.0053  0.9571  1.4972  1.3998  1.0935  2.4737  1.2063  1.7788
A2ML1   0.1024  0.092   0.0473  0.071   0.1227  0.2047  0.2481  0.1089  0.0499  0.1381  0.057   0.0953  0.0433  0.0651  0.0598  0.0434
A2M 5.4296  0.1688  2.4767  0.2507  0.5087  4.2835  2.2989  8.6027  3.1126  0.4565  0.167   2.9066  3.195   0.942   5.8904  6.7635
A4GALT  0.2918  11.5673 4.9554  0   1.6693  1.6301  0.4985  2.4444  0.6217  1.4638  3.2648  0.5773  3.1071  7.651   0.4068  5.133
A4GANLT 0   0   0   0   0.0575  0.1018  0   0.0422  0   0   0   0.0257  0.0276  0   0   0.0288
AAA1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AAA1    18.789  24.8681 29.8037 33.3986 37.8269 24.4719 21.1101 26.9985 21.9897 25.3416 26.77   23.1337 20.5193 27.0328 23.9777 29.5313
```

As you notice that AAA1 and A4GALt occurs two times in this data set and this is not an ideal scene for kind of computation I want to follow on this.

How can I get rid of this redundancy by eleminating the rows with same names, what are the possible ways of doing it and which is the best one? One way could be by keeping the row that has highest mean or maximum variance.

Small example of doing this with awk or perl or R would be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: You need to decide which of the duplicate records you want to delete - we can help you only with deleting them once the choice has been made. To *"keep the row that has maximum variance"* you must specify the population over whcih the variance should be calculated. Do you want to calculate the variance of all the fields after the first?

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ane '$s{$F[0]}++ or print' file
```

leaving duplicates with greater variance,

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -lane'
  $k = shift @F;
  $v = sum(@F)/@F;
  $s{$k} or push @r, $k;
  @{$s{$k}}{"l", "v"} = ($_, $v) if $v >$s{$k}{v};
 }{
  print $s{$_}{l} for @r;
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

In R

```
data[!duplicated(data$Gene), ]
```

assuming there is a column named `Gene`.

Duplicate row names are not allowed in R to begin with, so `Gene` would likely be in the first column.

Comment: Thank you, but if I have to keep the rows with maximum variance, then?

Answer (score 1):

to remove all the lines with the same 1st field except for the 1st occurrence:

```
awk '(a[$1]++ == 0){print $0}' file
```

Comment: Wow cool, is it discarding the rows based on mean?

Comment: Is it expression data from a chip? If yes, you probably have to carefully analyze the data because some genes might have more than one probe.

Comment: Agree, but what shall I do? I want to get rid of this duplicate names. Do you Know any other way of doing it?

Comment: replace `==` with `!=` and it will print duplicate lines. If you are trying to find a difference between samples, this "duplicate" data is valuable and you just cannot drop it. One of possible solutions is to rename genes in such duplicate lines, e.g. adding unique suffix (exact format depends on software you are using for further analysis). Talk to your PI if you are unsure.

Answer (score 1):

An awk solution could be as simply as if you keep just the first ocurrence:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' infile
```

Comment: what if I want to keep the row that has maximum variance?

Comment: Do you mean the total numeric value of the other fields?

Comment: Not exactly, variance is measure of variability between data.

Comment: By comparing the values in column 2 to column 16.